# Jquery jtable sorting child table

Tags: jquery-jtable

General query at this stage - I can post code if needs be but I shall probably have to simplify it a bit first.
I have used jtable quite a bit but I am having trouble getting sorting to work on a child table - are there fundamental differences between sorting a child table and a parent table?

When I put in the custom listAction function on the child table definition with parameters (postData, jtParams), and sorting: true on the definition, jtParams just comes through as an empty object.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [JqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) library. This may not answer your question but it's better if you post your code and everyone can see what are you trying.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

It was necessary to use different parameter names for the parameters passed into the listAction custom function for the child table otherwise I guess they are conflicting with the parent table variable names.  I changed my custom function definition in the child table to listAction: function(pData, jParams) { ... } and all was well.